# How can I import AggregatorV3Interface

Tags: import, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

**I'm trying to import AggregatorV3 but the file is nowhere to be found here is my code;
I'm sorry in advance i'm still a beginner programmer.**

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract Lottery {
    address payable[] public players; //to keep track of all players, payable array
    uint256 public usdEntryFee;
    AggregatorV3Intefrace internal ethUsdPriceFeed;

    constructor(address _priceFeedAddress) public {
        usdEntryFree = 50 * (10**18);
        ethUsdPriceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress); //we need to pass the address of aggv3 in constructor
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        //payable since we want them to pay in eth
        //50 $ minimum
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {}

    function startLottery() public {}

    function endLottery() public {}
}
```

**here is my Yaml file:**

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1

compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
    - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```

**here is the error:**

```
(base) marc@Marcs-MacBook-Pro smartcontract-lottery % brownie compile
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.8.11
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

ParserError: Source "/Users/marc/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File not found.
 --> contracts/Lottery.sol:4:1:
  |
4 | import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried changing
compiler:
solc:
remappings:
- '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
to @0.2.1
I also tried changing solidity version to a newer version and it's not working
Thanks in advance!

Comment: when i try to manually install using: 
brownie pm install smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
it says file already exists

Answer (score 3):

**I solved it by doing:**
npm install @chainlink/contracts --save

[**and in the yaml file doing:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axYng.png)

Comment: That's great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by replacing
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
with
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
My mistake, cheers!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

**use v0.6 instead of v0.8**

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was also stuck in a similar problem. Make sure that the brownie-config.yaml file is not inside the test folder and is kept seperately. Hope this helps.
[check the below image to see how I saved my brownie-config.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NqEF.png)